# how to mapping args(string) to string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

how to mapping args(string) to string in mysql?

Each of the two column contains data as follows:

| args | message |
| --- | --- |
| apple, delicious | %s are %s |
| banana, not good, cheap | %s are %s, but %s |

Desired result:

apple are delicious

banana are not good, but cheap

Comment: should be done in SQL query or can be done in code after fetching data from DB ?, if code which language ?

Comment: Only SQL or procedure can be used

Comment: Split message by `'%s'` substring and args by `','` then combine back.

Comment: This is not really appropriate for SQL.  I would suggest that you use a different tool, such as Python, to handle this.